# SQLITE: Merge tables from different databases with Primary Key Constraint

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, constants, primary-key

I want to concatenate/append tables from 2 different databases (database X and Y).

```
ATTACH "all\tab_X.db" AS db1;
ATTACH "all\tab_Y.db" AS db2;

INSERT INTO db1.PAYMENT SELECT * FROM db2.PAYMENT
```

However this is giving me this error: **UNIQUE constraint failed: PAYMENT.ID**

How do I create a new column that combines the ID with db name (eg: X_123, Y_123) and make that the primary key?

**Table DB X**

| Pmt_ID | P_CUSTOMER_NAME | P_CASH_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC ENTERPRISE | 1035.18 |
| 2 | RAS HOLDING | 385.19 |
| 3 | SEMANGAT BHD | 622.21 |

**Table DB Y**

| Pmt_ID | P_CUSTOMER_NAME | P_CASH_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ZNZ MINI MARKET | 338.14 |
| 2 | SEMANGAT SDN BHD | 298.92 |
| 3 | TAFFANY MARKETING | 253.34 |

**Result I want**

| PK | Pmt_ID | P_CUSTOMER_NAME | P_CASH_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X1 | 1 | ABC ENTERPRISE | 1035.18 |
| X2 | 2 | RAS HOLDING | 385.19 |
| X3 | 3 | SEMANGAT BHD | 622.21 |
| Y1 | 1 | ZNZ MINI MARKET | 338.14 |
| Y2 | 2 | SEMANGAT SDN BHD | 298.92 |
| Y3 | 3 | TAFFANY MARKETING | 253.34 |

Comment: You can't change the primary key in an existing table.

Comment: Hmm..How do I create a new table in a new db file from these two tables

Comment: Post sample data of the 2 existing tables and the expected result of the new table to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First attach the 3 databases:

```
ATTACH "all\tab_X.db" AS db1;
ATTACH "all\tab_Y.db" AS db2;
ATTACH "all\tab_Z.db" AS db3;
```

Create the new table:

```
CREATE TABLE db3.PAYMENT(Pmt_ID TEXT PRIMARY KEY, P_CUSTOMER_NAME TEXT, P_CASH_AMOUNT REAL);
```

Finally insert the rows:

```
INSERT INTO db3.PAYMENT(Pmt_ID, P_CUSTOMER_NAME, P_CASH_AMOUNT) 
SELECT 'X' || Pmt_ID, P_CUSTOMER_NAME, P_CASH_AMOUNT FROM db1.PAYMENT
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Y' || Pmt_ID, P_CUSTOMER_NAME, P_CASH_AMOUNT FROM db2.PAYMENT
```